# How to trigger animation using react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs

The problem is I have a form with three states: error, info, and success. Depending on there a response from server am firing toaster using above states I need to add a fade in-out animation when a response from the server is available.

toasterService.js

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';
 import {Transition} from 'react-transition-group';
 import './toasterService.css'

 export default function ToasterService(content, timeout, style) {
const inProp = useState(true); // always call hook on top level
const duration = timeout;
const transitionStyles = {
    entering: {opacity: 1},
    entered: {opacity: 1},
    exiting: {opacity: 0},
    exited: {opacity: 0},
};

let defaultStyle = {};

switch (style) {
    case 'info' :
        defaultStyle = {
            transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out`,
            opacity: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#00c5dc',
            color: '#ffffff'
        };
        break;

    case 'success' :
        defaultStyle = {
            transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out`,
            opacity: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#8ebe4b',
            color: '#ffffff'
        };
        break;
    case 'danger' :
        defaultStyle = {
            transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out`,
            opacity: 0,
            backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
            color: '#ffffff'
        };
        break;
    default :
}


return (<div className="main-alert">

        <Transition in={inProp} timeout={duration}>
            {state => (
                <div style={{
                    ...defaultStyle,
                    ...transitionStyles[state]
                }}>
                    {content}
                </div>
            )}
        </Transition>
    </div>

);
}
```

Login.js

```
import ToastService from '../../services/core/toasterService';
// on click of login btn
  socialSignIn = () => {
    let obj = {};
    obj = this.state;

    fetch(url,
        {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(obj)

        }).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.json());
          ToastService('success', 5000,'info');
        return res.json();

    })
};
```

Toast Service receiving 3 arguments but the toaster is not appearing. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently built a Toastr component myself, with basic functionality using `styled-components`, `animejs` and `react-transition-group` that might help you to get it right.

**Note:** I think it's easier to use `animejs` rather than setting styles for each phase of the transition. You basically get the reference for the entering or exiting element and animate it how you like using `animejs`.

`react-transition-group` will give you a reference to the element from these props:

```
<Transition
  key={item.id}
  onEntering={animateEnter}  // animateEnter will have a reference to the element
  onExiting={animateExit} // animateExist will have a reference to the element
  timeout={{
    enter: 500,
    exit: 500
  }}
  unmountOnExit={true} // I was testing, but I don't think this prop is necessary in my component
>
```

[See working example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-rubin-xjqc1)

[image]

This is the code:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Toastr from "./Toastr";
import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Toastr>
      <SomeComponent />
    </Toastr>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Toastr.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { TransitionGroup, Transition } from "react-transition-group";
import anime from "animejs";
import ToastrContext from "./ToastrContext";

// CREATE A USE TOASTER HOOK ?
// MAYBE CREATE AN APP STATE TO STORE THE TOASTS

const S = {};

S.FixedContainer = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  /* right: 5px; */
  /* left: 0; right: 0; */
  /* CENTER IT HORIZONTALLY */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
`;

S.ToastContainer = styled.div`
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* padding-left: 10px; */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #39c16c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;

function Toastr(props) {
  const lastToastLengthRef = useRef(0);
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([]);
  const toastID = useRef(0);

  console.log("Toastr rendering...");
  console.log(toasts);

  function addNewToast(toast) {
    setToasts(prevState => {
      const aux = Array.from(prevState);
      aux.push({ msg: toast, id: toastID.current });
      toastID.current = toastID.current + 1;
      return aux;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (toasts.length > lastToastLengthRef.current) {
      console.log("useEffect: Toast was added...");
      // TOAST WAS ADDED
      setTimeout(() => {
        setToasts(prevState => {
          const aux = Array.from(prevState);
          aux.shift();
          return aux;
        });
      }, 1000);
      lastToastLengthRef.current = toasts.length;
      return;
    }
    lastToastLengthRef.current = toasts.length;
  }, [toasts]);

  function animateEnter(element) {
    anime({
      targets: element,
      opacity: 0,
      duration: 0
    });
    anime({
      targets: element,
      opacity: 1,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 2000
    });
  }

  function animateExit(element) {
    anime({
      targets: element,
      opacity: 0,
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      duration: 2000
    });
  }

  // const toastItems = toasts.map((item,index) =>
  //   <S.ToastContainer key={item.id}>{item.msg}</S.ToastContainer>
  // );

  const toastItems = toasts.map((item, index) => (
    <Transition
      key={item.id}
      onEntering={animateEnter}
      onExiting={animateExit}
      timeout={{
        enter: 500,
        exit: 500
      }}
      unmountOnExit={true}
    >
      <S.ToastContainer>{item.msg}</S.ToastContainer>
    </Transition>
  ));

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <S.FixedContainer>
        <TransitionGroup component={null}>{toastItems}</TransitionGroup>
        {/* {toastItems} */}
      </S.FixedContainer>
      <ToastrContext.Provider value={addNewToast}>
        {props.children}
      </ToastrContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

// Toastr.whyDidYouRender = true;

export default Toastr;
```

**ToastrContext.js**

```
import React from "react";

const ToastrContext = React.createContext(null);

export default ToastrContext;
```

**SomeComponent.js (will emit toasts)**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import ToastrContext from "./ToastrContext";
import styled from "styled-components";

function SomeComponent() {
  const sendToast = useContext(ToastrContext);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Hey! Click for some toasts!</div>
      <button onClick={() => sendToast("This is your toast!")}>Click</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default SomeComponent;
```